# Cross-domain scriptable Silverlight application

Tags: javascript, silverlight, browser, silverlight-4.0, cross-domain

I'm having problems with cross-domain application hosting with Silverlight.

I have an application hosted on a different domain and included with the following HTML code to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function succ( sender, args ) {
    console.log("SUCCESS");
    console.log(sender);
    console.log(args);
}
function err( sender, args ) {
    console.log("FAILURE");
    console.log(sender);
    console.log(args);
}
</script>
<object width="400" height="20" id="app" type="application/x-silverlight-2" data="data:application/x-silverlight-2,">
    <param name="minruntimeversion" value="4.0.41108.0"/>
    <param name="autoupgrade" value="false"/>
    <param name="onerror" value="err"/>
    <param name="onload" value="succ"/>
    <param name="enablehtmlaccess" value="true"/>
    <param name="source" value="http://example.com/app.xap"/>
</object>
```

But if the `app.xap` application is hosted on a different domain from this HTML code, the [onLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838107%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) `succ` function is called without arguments, so it logs the following lines:

```
SUCCESS
undefined
undefined
```

If i host on the same domain it logs the correct lines:

```
SUCCESS
UserControl {}
undefined
```

So in the first case I could not reach the `[ScriptableMember]` annotated methods from javascript because I don't have any reference to the application.

In the `AppManifest.xml` file, I included the attribute needed by the `HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject` method as this:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            ExternalCallersFromCrossDomain="ScriptableOnly"
>
    <Deployment.Parts>
    </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

The `xap` file is transferred with `application/x-silverlight-app` `Content-Type`, so this isn't the problem either.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you've registered an external object named "Thingy".

You should be able to access it via the `Content` property of the html object element.  Place an `id="mySL"` on the object tag.  Now try this code:-

```
function succ( sender, args ) { 
    console.log("SUCCESS"); 
    console.log(document.getElementById("mySL").Content.Thingy); 
    console.log(args); 
}
```

Just be sure to register "Thingy" early in your code like in the constructor of the class you use as the root visual.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'll try it tomorrow, cause I don't have my virtual machine here.

Comment: I've modified the source of my silverlight app and my success method, but it does not work. :(

Comment: oh, it works I had to put all of my scriptable code to my root visual class (I don't know why).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, and solved as topic starter described in his comment

> I had to put all of my scriptable code to my root visual class